# How can I get a Peru long-stay visa?

Tags: visas, long-stay-visas, peru, spanish-citizens

I plan to go to Peru for 5 months. I'm looking at the tourist visa, but is is only good for 3 months. How can I get a visa that would let me stay for at least 5 months? I'm in Spain.

Comment: Visas generally depend on the activity you plan to pursue in the country you're traveling to.  What are you hoping to do in Peru for 5 months?

Comment: @phoog My girlfirend is going to do Erasmus and i plan go with her

Answer (score 1):

A tourist visa is obviously the only option if you're going as a tourist for more than 90 days in a 180-day period (for less than that, you do not need any visa).

You get it from [a Peruvian consulate in Spain](http://www.consulado.pe/es/Madrid/tramite/Paginas/Expedicion-de-Visa-de-Turista.aspx). The link is to the one in Madrid, with a list of the required documents.

Has the consulate explicitly said that they aren't issuing tourist visas valid for more than 90 days?